# Asp net core MVC View creating view default encoding VS 2017

Tags: asp.net-mvc, encoding, view, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

maybe trivial question but i couldnt find an answer...

When i am creating view via scaffolding this created view is saved with encoding "Central European (windows) - Codepage 1250" instead of "Unicode (UTF - 8 with signature) - Codepage 65001". **I have in my layout page**: *charset="utf-8" 
   name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"*

Now i have to re-save every view with save as with encoding option and set the right encoding manually because if not some characters would be displayed in browser with questin marks.

Is it possibility to set default encoding for scaffolding of views?